# how to provide access token in postmen for Asana API requests

Tags: postman, asana-api

Hello I am trying to use [Postman](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/906519/asana/6YySEFh#296b2732-5573-a951-f4ba-d426dd92a161) for sending requests to [Asana API](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options), but I am unable to Provide its Authorisation part

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

I already have :

1. Personal Token: ******
2. Client ID : *******
3. Client Secret: ***********

Can somebody explain me the other parts to provide at postman

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its as simple as Providing Headers.

Just See the Screenshot below and provide your Personal Token here

[image]

You can use this [Asana Postman Collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/906519/asana/6YySEFh#4b863534-9e0c-9909-090d-f2f3a2601b82) for knowing all fields